# System.OutOfMemoryException on Linq Joins

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, out-of-memory

I have this query below :

```
var data = (from ftr in db.TB_FTR
            join mst in db.TB_MST on ftr.MST_ID equals mst.MST_ID
            join trf in db.TB_TRF on mst.TRF_ID equals trf.ID
            select new TRFData 
            { 
                City = ftr.FTR_CITY, 
                County = ftr.FTR_COUNTY, 
                Type = trf.TRF_TYPE 
            }).ToList();
```

TB_FTR table contains 3,000,000 rows, TB_MST has 1,100,000 rows and TB_TRF has 340 rows. How can I make this join work? Is there a trick or workaround for this? Thanks.

Comment: Do you *really* need all the rows? no `where` clause?

Comment: Why use `ToList` upfront?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Calling `ToList` you force the execution of the query and you ask **all** the data of the query to be loaded in memory in a List. Instead of following this approach, you could use either a streaming approach, not a bufferring one like you do, in which you would get one element at a time or even better you could follow a paging approach to get the first 100 records, then the next 100 records (on another request) and so on and so forth.

*Streaming*

```
var items = (from ftr in db.TB_FTR
             join mst in db.TB_MST on ftr.MST_ID equals mst.MST_ID
             join trf in db.TB_TRF on mst.TRF_ID equals trf.ID
             select new TRFData 
             { 
                 City = ftr.FTR_CITY, 
                 County = ftr.FTR_COUNTY, 
                 Type = trf.TRF_TYPE 
             });

foreach(var item in items)
{
    // ..
}
```

*Paging*

```
var pageSize = 100;
var pageNumber = 1;

var first100Items = items.Skip(pageSize*PageNumber)
                         .Take(paeSize)
                         .ToList();
```